# Manifest merger failed. After adding and linking react-native-splash-screen

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

**Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31 is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.**

**RN v0.55.4**

**react-native-splash-screen v3.0.6**

**app/build.gradle:**

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
         minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
      signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies { 
    compile project(':react-native-audio')
    compile project(':react-native-track-player')
    compile project(':react-native-background-job')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-notifications')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-restart')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk-corrected')
    compile(project(':react-native-google-sign-in')) { //ForGoogleSignIn
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }

    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0"//Added
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0" //ForGoogleSignIn

}
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services" ///ForGoogleSignIn

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

**AndroidMenifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.happycow" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "https://www.happycow.com/post” -->
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.myapp.com" android:pathPrefix="/post" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider219275678834893" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:exported="true" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationBootEventReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
        <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**react-native-splash-screen/android/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

Comment: can you try setting the dependency manually to match all the versions? for example:

implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

Comment: Where should i write  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0?

Comment: the build.gradle file. implementation is the same as your compile.
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0' compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

Comment: A.Myapp/android/app/build.gradle  or  B.Myapp/node_modules/react-native-splash-screen/android/build.gradle  ??

Comment: Myapp/android/app/build.gradle

Comment: see answer: this is a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56803943/manifest-merger-failed-after-import-a-module/56853863#56853863

Answer (score 0):

I find out that where ever in my project ,third-party modules uses other version of `com.google.android.gms:play-services`. So in every third-party modules i put same version of `com.google.android.gms:play-services`.My project has `11.8.0` version so i put same to third-party modules `com.google.android.gms:play-services` if they have.

NO need to do extra work just change the `google-services` version of modules to the same as my project `google-services` version.