# Manifest merger failed after import a module

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-manifest

Hi I am developing a sdk, and when I add these SDK into a app proyect I get the following error:

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91

```
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-125:19 to override.
```

The build.gradle are the followings

App build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':sdkA')
    implementation project(':sdkB')

    implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.28032'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v14:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.4.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.woxthebox:draglistview:1.6.3'
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.16'

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Google Lifecycle Components
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
}
```

build.gradle of sdkA

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.28032'

    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }


    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'



    // Google Lifecycle Components
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

build.gradle of sdkB

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1"
}
```

How can solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Comment: You probably would want to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56696860/how-to-fixed-manifest-merger-failed-error-when-trying-to-implement-a-library

Comment: You are using both, support libraries and androidx libraries in your app. Migrate your project to androidx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've been tackling this issue myself for the last day or so. nightmare.

but I have it working now at least for the project I've been working on which is quite large and with lots of additional android dependencies.

See this issue where Mike Hardy has been a great help. https://github.com/mikehardy/jetifier/issues/27

**I would recommend to avoid AndroidX until 0.60.0 has landed.**

**SOURCE OF THE PROBLEM**
the source of the problem for most of us is the `+` range selector in gradle dependencies.

as shown here as an example in react-native-google-analytics-bridge:

```
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${safeExtGet('googlePlayServicesVersion', '+')}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:${safeExtGet('googlePlayServicesVersion', '+')}"
```

for most of us we're not setting a googlePlayServicesVersion value in the top level android/build.gradle

so we'll want to specify `googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"` + because theres various other google service packages available and they're not all at the same version number. this will capture 16.X.X and not go above. 17.X.X holds further issues.

And we also want to set supportLibVersion to 28.0.0 which is used by the android support libraries: com.android.support:appcompat-v7 the most common.

**SOLUTION**

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
    }
...
```

AndroidManifest.xml
top line:
`<manifest 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

application tag:
`tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
      android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"`

ensure your gradle-wrapper.properties using 4.10.1

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`

and finally ensure you are not using android X.

gradle.properties:

```
android.enableJetifier=false
android.useAndroidX=false
```

**Additional Step (You might need this)**

failing that doesn't work try adding jetifier as well. We'll use this to run through your node_modules and ensure everything is using the non androidx libraries.

`npm i jetifier --save-dev` or `yarn add jetifier --dev`

then add to postinstall script

```
"scripts": {
   "postinstall": "jetify -r"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try applying the suggestion, adding

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
```

to the application tag